# Shader Graph для Unity UI

Tags: unity3d, шейдеры, unity3d-ui

Пытаюсь создать шейдер, который бы заставлял светиться элементы UI.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Во вкладке Scene шейдер работает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако уже на вкладке Game (независимо от того, запущен проект или нет), а так же в собранном проекте - нет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это баг, или так и должно быть? Я не силён в шейдерах, и допускаю, что это я что-то делаю не так.

Существует ли на данный момент возможность с помощью Shader Graph создавать рабочие шейдеры для элементов интерфейса?

Версия Unity: 2019.1.2f1

**UPDATE**

Шейдер работает, если применён к UI, канвас которого рендерит в режиме World Space или Screen Space - Camera. Но это всё равно не то, необходимо, чтобы он работал в оверлее. Возможно ли это?

Comment: А шейдер вы в итоге какой сделали? Где скриншот?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker добавил скриншот в начало вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переведу ответ, который мне [дали](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56226496/shader-graph-for-ui-works-in-scene-tab-but-not-in-game-tab) на англоязычном SO:

Переведите холст в режим `Screen Space - Camera` или `World Space`.

Это необходимо из-за того, что шейдерам визуализации (render shaders), в отличие от вычисляемых шейдеров (compute shaders), для работы требуется камера, а элементы UI, работающие в режиме `Screen Space - Overlay`, её не используют.